# Lebesgue integration: Existence of double integral, but not Lebesgue integrable.

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to determine whether or not $f(x,y) = \dfrac{\sin(x)\sin(y)}{x^2+y^2}$ is integrable on $E = \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \times \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

I'm thinking this is a bit of a trick question:

$f$ is continuous a.e. so it is measurable on $E$ and for any $y \neq 0$, $x \mapsto \dfrac{\sin(x)\sin(y)}{x^2+y^2}$ is continous on $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ , hence integrable. Also, since $f$ is an odd function:

$\displaystyle\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} f(x,y) \ dx = \underbrace{\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} f(x,y) \ dy}_\text{by symmetry} = 0$

and therefore

$\displaystyle\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} f(x,y) \ dx \ dy = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} f(x,y) \ dy \ dx = 0$

However, since $f$ is Lebesgue integrable if and only if $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable the above result doesn't imply that $f$ is integrable on $E$ - and I have a feeling that

$\displaystyle\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} |f(x,y)| \ dx \ dy \ $ is not finite, but I'm having trouble showing this. I've been trying to evaluate:

$\displaystyle\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} |f(x,y)| \ dx $ to argue that the double integral doesn't exist, but I haven't been able to get anywhere in evaluating the integral. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $|\sin x|\le |x|$ and $x^2+y^2\ge 2|xy|$.

> **Conclusion:** $|f(x,y)|\le\frac1{2}$ when $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$, so $f$ is integrable on $E$.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I should've looked for a dominating function before going down the route I did.

Comment: @Noble.: You are welcome.